# Larry Niven (possibly!) question from Facebook

Tags: story-identification

I've just spotted this on Facebook today, I sent a question to the poster but no reply.

> "I think it was Larry Niven wrote a time travel story about a bunch of dedicated time cops who spent their lives protecting the time stream by traveling to the past to fix meddling.  In the beginning of the story they are all normal future society humans, and 100 pages later they are blue amoebas living in a world that they have created, one "woops" at a time, and them with no clue that they have changed the very nature of themselves and their universe, they still think they are doing a great job of saving the timestream from meddling."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the Facebook poster has  conflated some time cop story with William Tenn's
*[Brooklyn Project](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41581)* which does end with the people who set off a time probe to the deep past having turned themselves into bizarre creatures, without noticing the change.

The story ends like this:

> The apparatus has rested at last in the fractional conveyance; shall we
> view it subtly?" They all agreed, and their bloated purpled bodies
> dissolved into liquid and flowed up and around to the apparatus. When
> they reached its four square blocks, now no longer shrilling
> mechanically, they rose, solidified, and regained their slime-washed
> forms. "See," cried the thing that had been the acting secretary to
> the executive assistant on press relations. "See, no matter how
> subtly! Those who billow were wrong: we haven't changed." He extended
> fifteen purple blobs triumphantly. "Nothing has changed!"

The "Time cop" business might be a misremembering of the background of the Tenn story, which features a dictatorial "security" apparatus.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, that somebody has mixed up something like Poul Anderson's *Time Patrol* series with Tenn's "Brooklyn Project". It should be noted that Tenn's short story took up barely 6 pages in [*Planet Stories*](https://archive.org/details/Planet_Stories_Canadian_Ed._v03n12_1948-Fall/page/n91/mode/2up), not "100 pages".

Comment: Yeah I'll accept that, it sounds like the question....still no reply from the Facebook guy!